# where can i find preprocessed fmri data set for alzheimer's disease

Tags: neuroscience, neuroimaging, fmri, alzheimer

I want to work on identification of Alzheimer's patients based on given fMRI data.Basically, I want to implement the following paper https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25907414. Where can I get preprocessed dataset or how can I preprocess dataset?

Answer (score 3):

See https://www.reddit.com/r/neuro/comments/5y4pta/does_anyone_know_where_i_can_find_a_repository_of/ for a similar question.

Websites that were posted there include http://www.humanconnectome.org/data/, http://neurovault.org, http://www.ppmi-info.org, https://openfmri.org/, http://fcon_1000.projects.nitrc.org/indi/abide/ and http://radiopaedia.org.  Some of those are repositories of data for other diseases, but their control scans could be useful.